# MsDeploy : how to have many productions environment

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, msdeploy

Today, I have a production environment hosted on IIS and using MsDeploy to be deployed. So the database connection string is set in appsetting.Production.json.

But i have to make a second production environment. So i will create a new publish profile for this environment but how can i set the connection string for this new environment ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Are they being deployed to separate machines? You can override the settings in `appsettings.json` by using Environment settings. You don't need to change your code to do this as ASP.NET Core does all the work for you.

In short, settings are read in the following order, with the later ones overriding values from the earlier ones:

1. Files (appsettings.json, appsettings.{Environment}.json, where
   {Environment} is the app's current hosting environment)
2. Azure Key Vault
3. User secrets (Secret Manager) (in the Development environment only)
4. Environment variables
5. Command-line arguments

So, on your second production machine you can add an `Environment variable` to override the setting in `appsettings.Production.json`.
If you are using SQL Server then you can set the `SQLCONNSTR_` environment variable to override your setting, add your connection name at the end e.g. `SQLCONNSTR_DefaultConnection`.

If you are going to use environment variables to override the settings on one machine I suggest you do it for all production machines for consistency.

Take a look at this section in the [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#providers) for the full configuration sequence.

Information regarding the specific `ConnectionString` settings are [on the same page as above](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#environment-variables-configuration-provider).